# how to get rid of `Wide character in print at`?

Tags: perl, unicode, file-io

I have file `/tmp/xxx` with next content:

```
00000000 D0 BA D0 B8 │ D1 80 D0 B8 │ D0 BB D0 B8 │ D0 BA     к и р и л и к
```

When I read content of file and print it I get the error:

```
Wide character in print at ...
```

The source is:

```
use utf8;
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', '/tmp/xxx';
print scalar <$fh>
```

The output from print is:

```
кирилик
```

Comment: Your `use utf8` tells Perl the source code file has utf8 chars in it. You need to open `STDOUT` with utf8 support or `binmode` it.

Comment: @simbabque: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `use utf8`: the code is entirely ASCII. Most likely the first line of `/tmp/xx` contains extended characters.

Comment: I know @Borodin. That was my point.

Comment: @simbabque: Ah. I read it as the problem being because the code has `use utf8` but `STDOUT` is in byte mode.

Comment: @Borodin no, I mentioned the `use utf8` because it looked like OP thinks it's useful here.

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, I see your meaning now

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `use utf8` means Perl expects your source code to be UTF-8.

The `open` pragma can change the encoding of the standard filehandles:

```
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );
```

And, whatever is going to deal with your output needs to expect UTF-8 too. If you want to see it correctly in your terminal, then you need to set up that correctly (but that's nothing to do with Perl).

Comment: Thanks. This one should have been the accepted answer instead. I think the UTF-8 encoding for standard file handles should nowadays be the default for Perl.

Comment: Changed this one to accepted answer. It is better.

Answer (score 29):

You're printing to STDOUT which isn't expecting UTF8.
Add

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");
```

to change that on the already opened handle.

Comment: `use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";` is better. This also binmodes STDIN and STDERR, and sets the default encoding layer for `open` in its lexical scope (so, for example, you could use `open my $fh, '<', '/tmp/xxx'` instead of `open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', '/tmp/xxx'`).

Comment: @ikegami “better” depends on the use case… it might not be better.

Comment: @mirabilos, I can't think of a case where it wouldn't be better. Keep in mind that it just sets the default, and can be overridden.

Comment: @ikegami if your stdin or other files may be in different encodings, for example? (more specifically, if you’d write `binmode($fh, "encoding(UTF-8)");` instead, but not just then)

Comment: @mirabilos Again, you can override it for the other files that need a different encoding (by using `:encoding(...)` in the `open`)

Comment: There’s no `open()` call. Maybe you get the fh from somewhere, in this case `File::Temp::tempfile`.